# Problema de linkagem em projeto com mais de um arquivo fonte

Tags: c, linkagem

Esta é à minha função. Dá me erro quando chamo na função main.

Este é o cabeçalho da minha função, no arquivo função1.h

```
int eleminar_numeros_repetidos(int *vec, int n, int *vec1);
```

Arquivo função1.c:

```
void organizar_vetor(int *vec, int n){

   int i,j;

   for(i=0 ; i <n-1; i=i+1)
   {
       for(j=i+1 ; j<n ; j=j+1)
       {
           if (*(vec +i) >*(vec+j))
           {
            int aux =*(vec+i);
            *(vec+i)=*(vec+j);
            *(vec+j)=aux;
           }

       }

   }
}

int eleminar_numeros_repetidos(int *vec, int n, int *vec1){

 organizar_vetor(vec,n);

 int i,j;

   for(i=0 ; i <n-1; i++)
   {
       for(j=i+1 ; j<n ; j++)
       {
           vec[i]=vec1[i];

            if (vec1[i] == vec1[j])
           {

            int k;   
              for (k = j; k <n-1 ; k++)
              {
                  vec1[k]=vec1[k+1];
                  j--;n--;
              }


           } 

       }

   }
   return n;

}
```

Erro:

```
gcc ex09.c
/tmp/ccYQaeVL.o: In function `main':
ex09.c:(.text+0x112): undefined reference to `eleminar_numeros_repetidos'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ex09.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Seu problema não é no código da função em sim. Este problema acontece quando você chama uma função que está definida em um arquivo fonte a partir de outro, mas por algum motivo o linker não está conseguindo vincular a chamada com a função em si. Seria mais útil para podermos ajudá-lo se você publicasse como você declarou a funcão: nome, parâmetros. Você está utilizando um arquivo de cabeçalho, certo? Verifique se a declaração da função nele bate com a declaração no arquivo fonte.

Comment: int eleminar_numeros_repetidos(int *vec, int n, int *vec1); está é a minha função1.h (onde está o cabeçalho) ;  -    @  C. E. Gesser

Comment: E no arquivo `funcao1.c`, como está? É preciso também garantir que no arquivo que contém a função `main` esteja sendo dado `#include "função1.h"`

Comment: Atualizei a minha publicação, coloquei mais códigos do meu programa. E no meu main chamo à função #include "funcao1.h" @ C. E. Gesser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe a linha de comando que foi utilizada para compilar:

```
gcc ex09.c
```

Você está instruindo o compilador para gerar um executável a partir de um arquivo fonte apenas, mas seu projeto é composto por mais de um. Por isso o compilador reclama que, no momento de gerar o executável, ele não acha a implementação de uma função.

Você tem duas opções

Compilar e linkar todos os fontes ao mesmo tempo:

```
gcc ex09.c funcao1.c
```

Ou compilar os fontes individualmente e linkar em separado:

```
gcc -c ex09.c
gcc -c funcao1.c
gcc ex09.o funcao1.o
```

Lembando que o parâmetro `-c` instrui o gcc a apenas compilar os arquivos fonte, sem linkar o executável final.

Comment: Obrigado pela vossa ajuda, já consegui resolver o problema. Mas não consigo eliminar os números repetidos @ C. E. Gesser

Comment: @Programador: Eu achei melhor alterar o título desta questão para ficar mais de acordo com o problema tratado aqui, que era o de linkagem. Eu dei uma olhada rápida no seu algoritmo, e achei curiosa a linha com o comando `vec[i]=vec1[i];`. Parece que você está descartando o conteúdo de `vec`, que você organizou umas linhas acima. Não está exatamente claro qual array é o de entrada e qual o de saída da função. Agora que já passamos dos problemas de compilação, você pode fazer mais testes. Se não conseguir resolver sugiro criar mais uma questão, agora sim sobre o algoritmo em si.

Answer (score 1):

Seu comando de compilação está errado:

```
gcc ex09.c      ### BAD!!!
```

Deve ser assim:

```
gcc -o ex09 ex09.c funcao1.c   ### GOOD :)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela vossa ajuda, já consegui resolver o problema. Mas não consigo eliminar os números repetidos @ José X.